# Do snow gustnadoes or anything similar occur at or near the summits of the highest Himalayas such as Mt Everest?

Tags: meteorology, mountains, snow, tornado

A [gustnado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustnado) is a landspout (i.e. a "mini-tornado") that isn't connected to the ambient cloud base (if there is any). Mt Everest, the highest point on Earth, there is nothing "in the way" of colliding winds to form a snow gustnado on the summit. Cumulonimbus clouds can be as high as sixty thousand feet so perhaps even such gustnado could become a landspout (or snowspout). Is there enough area on or near the summit of Mt Everest (or another mountain in the Himalaya or on K2) and the right conditions possible for a snow gustnado or similar whirl spouts to form and persist for some time (and for how long) there?

Comment: @gansub You know there are satellites, right? Mars probes observed whirls on Mars from orbit too. But why round the clock? A climber might have coincidentally seen one. I'm asking whether this is likely, not necessarily whether one has actually seen such whirl.

Comment: It's the scale. Does a satellite have the resolution(spatial and temporal)  to observe a mesocale gamma event ?

Comment: @gansub I dunno. But dust whirls have been observed on Mars from orbit so I believe snow whirls can be observed (indirectly perhaps) from space if there are no clouds inbetween. But I wonder whether it is even possible or likely.

Comment: Mars is very different as its a thinner atmosphere. Here you have altitude plus the interval of gustanado at that height. I doubt it can sustain itself for longer than a few minutes with that vertical shear of the subtropical jetstream

Comment: @gansub Interesting.

Comment: Maybe you ought to change your location to USA not Himalayas - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H3XW0N7stg